# Verilog testbench for inout

Tags: verilog

Can anybody please help me out with how to write test benches for inout ports in Verilog? I can't instantiate them as reg type variables in the test bench.

Comment: What's the big deal? You will have an inout in TB as well. And you have to drive it from only one side at any given time, either from DUT or TB side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to assign value to bidirectional port in verilog?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/22220/how-to-assign-value-to-bidirectional-port-in-verilog)

Answer (score 2):

You can't drive an `inout` directly as a `reg`. `inout` types need to be `wire`. So, you need a workaround.

The workaround is creating a driver pin that shares the same wire as the module signal. To do this, define a `reg` variable for your 3-state test signal, then `assign` it to the `inout` pin to connect it.

As follows:

```
module my_testbench;

wire inout_pin;   // bidirectional signal from DUT
reg inout_drive;  // locally driven value
wire inout_recv;  // locally received value (optional, but models typical pad)

assign inout_pin = inout_drive;
assign inout_recv = inout_pin;
```

then later in your testbench, you can manipulate the drive state of the tristate pin:

```
initial begin

inout_drive = 1'bz;    // default high-Z
```

later....

```
inout_drive = 1'b0;    // drive a value, propagates onto inout_pin
```

As you expect, the `inout_pin` will assume the value you drive it with `inout_drive` as long as the DUT signal is in high-Z state. Likewise, `inout_recv` will follow the value driven onto `inout_pin`.

Strictly speaking, you don't need `inout_recv` to use the value present on `inout_pin` in your test bench, but it reflects modeling a tristate I/O pin connected to the DUT.

Comment: And how will you read from the inout pin?

Comment: You don't have to do anything special; the inout can be used in a RHS expression as-is. I prefer to connect it separately with an `assign` however.

Answer (score 1):

You can test them the same way as you assign them from within the module:

```
reg dir;
reg gen;
wire bidir;

assign bidir = dir ? gen : 1'bz;

MyAmazingModule DUT (
    .myInOut(bidir)
);

initial begin
   dir = 0;
   gen = 0;
   ...
end
```

Comment: OP is asking about bidirs in testbenches, not in modules.

Comment: @hacktastical errm... There's no difference?! That works perfectly well in a testbench...